# Как быстро прочесть большой текстовый файл?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть json файл  размером 500 мб который нужно прочесть и обработать.
Идея была в многопоточном чтении. Запуск чтения новым потоков с того места где остановится предыдущий. Но застрял на непонятной ошибке: "Смещение и длина вышли за границы массива или значение счетчика превышает количество элементов от указателя до конца исходной коллекции."
Тело цикла в перспективе превращается в отдельный поток и в каждом таком потоке считывается кусок равный step из стрима.
Почему я получаю ошибку во время выполнения?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathToFile);

        int coreCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        List<int> steps = new List<int>();
        List<char[]> asb = new List<char[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < coreCount; i++)
        {

            int fileSize = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            int step = fileSize / coreCount;
            int startIndex = step * i;

            asb.Add(new char[step]);
            steps.Add(startIndex);
            results.Add("");

            reader.Read(asb[i],steps[i],step);



        }
    }
```

Comment: Не вижу в чем проблема. Но замечу, что если у вас не SSD, то параллельное чтение двух блоков файла с жесткого диска медленнее, чем последовательное раза в полтора, потому что головкам диска приходится мотаться то к началу то к середине файла (а движение головок это самая тормозная операция hdd). Лучше уж получить начальный блок, не особо большого размера, запустить в асинхронном режиме чтение следующего блока и пока он читается заниматься обработкой.

Comment: Не работает. Читает файл размером 5 кб дольше чем просто методом ReadToEnd  и отдельным парсингом.

Comment: 5 kb .... вы смеетесь видимо ... накладные расходы на всякие хитрые виды чтения файла гораздо выше, чем время чтения 5 кб. тем более, что очень вероятно, что у вас файл в кеше ОС находится. любые сравнения скорости обработки файлов имеет смысл проводить на файлах не умещающихся целиком в ОЗУ

Comment: 3 минуты на чтение файла 5 кб и более 20 мин на чтение 500мб, не это моя цель

Comment: если у вас 5 кб читаются 3 минуты, то вы делаете что то невероятно сложное. даже если по 1 байту читать и то быстрее будет (в тысячи раз быстрее). Если что, под "небольшой блок" в своем первом комменте я имел ввиду "несколько мегабайт"

Comment: Грубо говоря, текстовый файл (почти) невозможно читать в несколько потоков. Точка. Файл json ещё сложнее читать в несколько потоков; то есть дважды невозможно. Dixi. Вывод: читайте в один поток, парсьте стандартным Json-парсером. А уже разобранные данные можно обрабатывать в несколько потоков.

Comment: Все действия происходят в рамках асинхронной команды впф, каждое посимвольное чтение так же выполняет проверку на отмену команды, ничего сложнее этого нет. На домашнем ссд со скоростью чтения 3000 мегабайт в секунду выполнение ReadToEnd  файла 500 мб занимает около считанное кол-вол секунд, а потребление памяти просто зашкаливает и равно двум гигабайтам

Comment: "посимвольное" ... вот это и есть самое сложное... ОС с диска читает по 4 кб. значит запрашивать из файла менее 4 кб за один раз не имеет никакого смысла и операция настолько быстра что ее нельзя запускать как асинхронную. в асинхронном чтении есть смысл, когда вы читаете за раз хотя бы несколько мегабайт.

Comment: Многопоточное чтение с диска бесполезно, если только файл полностью не закэширован. Вы либо не правильно парсите, либо обрабатываете

Comment: [Json.Net умеет стримридер](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32227436/5752652). А читать 4 килобайта, чтобы потом взять из него один байт - это... мммм... ну в общем, придумайте сами нецензурное слово.